# Why is Movement not working in this Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame import *


pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600) , 0,24)
pygame.display.set_caption("Shooting Squad")
fillcolour=(255,255,255)
backG=('shooting.jpg')
player=('player.jpg')

x,y=0,0
movex,movey=0,0

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    if event.type==KEYDOWN:
        if event.key==K_LEFT:
            movex+=-1
        elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
            movex+=1
        elif event.key==K_UP:
            movey+=-1
        elif event.key==K_DOWN:
            movey+=1
x=movex
y=movey

backG=pygame.image.load('shooting.jpg')
player=pygame.image.load('player.jpg')

window.blit(backG,(0,0))
window.blit(player,(x,y)) 
pygame.display.update()
```

Ok, so basically the game loads up, with the background I want and the plyer that I want to move, however the character does not move when I use the key buttons.
Any ideas guys??
:)

Comment: Read free ebook (PDF) [Making Games with Python & Pygame](http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapters/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `while` construct to make sure the game runs until you quit.

Also, you need to make sure the position `x` & `y` change according to the keystrokes (`movex` & movey`)

Corrected code (untested)

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame import *


pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600) , 0,24)
pygame.display.set_caption("Shooting Squad")
fillcolour=(255,255,255)
backG=('shooting.jpg')
player=('player.jpg')

x,y=0,0
movex,movey=0,0

backG=pygame.image.load('shooting.jpg')
player=pygame.image.load('player.jpg')

while True: # Run the game forever (until quit event)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                movex+=-1
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                movex+=1
            elif event.key==K_UP:
                movey+=-1
            elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                movey+=1
    x += movex # Change the position according to the movement
    y += movey

    window.blit(backG,(0,0))
    window.blit(player,(x,y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

PS - I suspect that you will need to refresh the screen everytime before *blitting*.